# Two templates on Github Pages (one Jekyll and one Node in subdirectory)

Tags: node.js, github-actions, jekyll, github-pages

I have created my website on username.github.io using jekyll template. I want to use this address: username.github.io/blog to create my personal blog using NodeJS template (Hugo).

To this aim, I created a folder called blog in the main directory in repo, and moved the .github/workflows/main.yaml from the /blog to the main dir and used 'working-directory: ./blog' for different steps. After this, both of my websites went broken. Has anyone the same idea and could successfully implement it? Here is my repo:
https://github.com/ghazalrafiei/ghazalrafiei.github.io